Vite/Docker: localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
I'm trying to run a vanilla js vite project in docker:
docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5173:5173"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    command: npm run dev

Dockerfile
# Use the official lightweight Node.js 14 image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/node
FROM node:19

# Create and change to the app directory.
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy application dependency manifests to the container image.
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied.
# Copying this separately prevents re-running npm install on every code change.
COPY package*.json ./

# Install vite globally in the Docker container.
RUN npm install

# Install all dependencies.
RUN npm install -g vite

# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY . .

 docker-compose up --build
Creating network "vite-docker_default" with the default driver
Building app
[+] Building 4.9s (11/11) FINISHED                                               
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                        0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 622B                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:19                  0.7s
 => [internal] load build context                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 1.29kB                                         0.0s
 => [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/node:19@sha256:92f06fc13bcc09f1ddc51f6ebf  0.0s
 => CACHED [2/6] WORKDIR /usr/src/app                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [3/6] COPY package*.json ./                                      0.0s
 => [4/6] RUN npm install                                                   3.0s
 => [5/6] RUN npm install -g vite                                           1.0s
 => [6/6] COPY . .                                                          0.0s 
 => exporting to image                                                      0.1s 
 => => exporting layers                                                     0.1s 
 => => writing image sha256:916da68b6a643e1d85ea3625a71b5c2c49ca528b90f6d8  0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/vite-docker_app                          0.0s 

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
Creating vite-docker_app_1 ... done
Attaching to vite-docker_app_1
app_1  | 
app_1  | > vite-docker@0.0.0 dev
app_1  | > vite
app_1  | 
app_1  | 
app_1  |   VITE v5.2.10  ready in 130 ms
app_1  | 
app_1  |   ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
app_1  |   ➜  Network: use --host to expose

When I open http://localhost:5173/ in the browser I get:

There are no logs in the container

As the log says, Network: use --host to expose. Without it, Vite only accepts connections from the local machine. In a container, only the container itself is considered the local machine. Look here for a full answer.
